# Appropriate action against "Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')." error

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I prepared a csv file for LGBM machine learning and used the following code.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test=train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=333 )
lgbm_wrapper = LGBMClassifier(n_estimators=400)

evals = [(X_test, y_test)]
lgbm_wrapper.fit(X_train, y_train, early_stopping_rounds=100,
eval_metric="logloss", eval_set=evals, verbose=True)
preds = lgbm_wrapper.predict(X_test)
pred_proba = lgbm_wrapper.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]
```

But I face this kind of problem.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in
_assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan, msg_dtype)
104                     msg_err.format
105                     (type_err,
--> 106                      msg_dtype if msg_dtype is not None else
X.dtype)
107             )
108     # for object dtype data, we only check for NaNs (GH-13254)
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for
dtype('float64').
```

To solve this problem, I checked the data type of data first.

```
Date             object
A                float64
B                 int64
C                 int64
D                float64
E                float64
F                float64
G                float64
H                 object
dtype: object
```

X.dropna() was also pre-treated to eliminate NaN-related values. However, a float63 related error still occurs. I need a little help.
[image]

My data consists like this

Comment: Can you try rounding your float to 3 or 4 decimals, and revert if it doesn't work?

Comment: @shivam13juna I rounded to third decimal place but still doesn't work:(

Comment: It has to be a data problem Emma, you've to make sure all data points are both finite and not nan. Try placing some manual checks like checking for values greater than 999. 

Try that, if it doesn't work, and if data isn't private, share data with me I'll see

Comment: @shivam13juna So can't we use numbers over 999? I have a 4-digit data type among the data.Thank you very much for your reply!

Comment: Nah Nah, it's just for checking what values might be getting interpreted as NaN, try checking for numbers > 999999. Since you have 4-digit data, no row should have any value  > 999999. If there is, then that's the possible error.

Comment: @shivam13juna I checked all stuffs you said. There were no values above>9999 and data rows were 2357. Should I change the data format of float64?(Please check the contents of the image I modified in the article above.
)

Comment: Well, data definitely looks good, hard to say more without checking the entire data. BTW, when using dropna, you do know that X.dropna() isn't in place right, I hope for dropping NA you did X = X.dropna().

Comment: @shivam13juna Oh, I understand what you mean. But then, I encountered an error called "ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2348,2356]",when I use train_test_split function. Is it because there are samples omitted due to X = X.dropna()? My X.shape is  (2348, 15), y.shape is (2356,).

Comment: Precisely. now you can find out indices of when X is NaN and then drop corresponding indices for target too. You need to have same no of rows for training and target too right. Do accept my answer if it works out for ya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using dropna, you do know that X.dropna() isn't in place right, I hope for dropping NA you did X = X.dropna(), for the indices in which you drop X drop corresponding indices in target too.